# Show integrability of $g(u)=\begin{cases}g(\pi),u=-\pi\\\frac{\varphi(u)}{2\sin(\frac{u}{2})},u\in(-\pi,\pi)\setminus\{0,-\pi\}\\0,u=0.\end{cases} $

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, solution-verification, riemann-integration

Let's consider the $2\pi$ periodic and Riemann integrable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and  the function $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, with $\varphi(u)=\frac{f(x_0+u)+f(x_0-u)}{2}-f(x_0)$; and $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ arbitrarily chosen.

We want to show that the function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, where

\begin{align*}
&g(u)=\begin{cases}
g(\pi),&\text{ if } u=-\pi\\
\frac{\varphi(u)}{2\sin(\frac{u}{2})},&\text{ if } u\in (-\pi,\pi)\setminus\{0,-\pi\}\\
0,&\text{ if } u=0.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
is Riemann-integrable on $(-\pi,\pi)$.
We can assume that the two limits
\begin{align*}
&\lim\limits_{\underset{u>0}{u\to 0}} g(u):=a \text{ and }\lim\limits_{\underset{u<0}{u\to 0}} g(u):=b
\end{align*}
exist.

---

**My approach:**

We know that $h:(-\pi,\pi)\to\mathbb{R}$ with
\begin{align*}
&h(u)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\varphi(u)}{2\sin(\frac{u}{2})},&\text{ if } u\in (-\pi,\pi)\setminus\{0\}\\
0,&\text{ if } u=0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
is continuous at all points $u\neq0$. If we restrict $h$ to $(0,\pi)$, then we can make $h_{\mid (0,\pi) }$ continuous at point $0$ by setting $h_{\mid 0,\pi) }(0):=a$. We do the same with $h_{\mid (-\pi,0) }$, so $h_{\mid (-\pi,0) }(0):=b$. Hence, $h_{\mid (0,\pi)}$ and $h_{\mid (-\pi,0) }$ are continuous in each point and therefore Riemann-integrable. If I amend the following points again by setting
\begin{align*}
&h_{\mid (-\pi,0) }(-\pi):=g(\pi),~h_{\mid (-\pi,0) }(0):=0 \text{ and } h_{\mid (0,\pi) }(0):=0, 
\end{align*}
the restrictions $h_{\mid (-\pi,0)}$ and $h_{\mid (0,\pi) }$ remain Riemann-integrable. Now merging both restrictions $h_{\mid (-\pi,0)}$ and $h_{\mid (0,\pi) }$ gives us a new function, which we denote by $\hat{h}$, which is also Riemann integrable on $(-\pi,0)\cup (0,\pi)$. Finally, we see that $\hat{h}=g$ for all $u\in(-\pi,\pi)$, so $g$ is Riemann integrable on $(-\pi,\pi)$.

---

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't see the connection between the question and the title.

Comment: The exercise given is incoherently formulated. If $\mathrm{dom}f=(-\pi,\pi)$ and $\mathrm{dom}\phi=(-\pi,\pi)$, then it is not possible that $x_0\in(-\pi,\pi)$, because then, for some neighborhood of $\pi$, $u+x_0\gt\pi$, which is not in the domain of $f$.

Comment: @Angel, thanks for the remark. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My professor gave me the hint that I had assumed that $f$ is continuous. However, this might not be the case in general; we only know that $f$ is Riemann-integrable. Without $f$ being continuous I can't say that $\varphi$ and $h$ are continuous. So at this point my proof breaks.